# Laravel Queue with AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-queue

In my local server I can use the queue without problem, just using:
`php artisan queue:work`.

But in my server in AWS the queue don't running.

My connection queue is `database` and sync mails are sending without problem.

I'd checked in Job table and I can see my queues but for unknown reason it's never running.

Is necessary to do some different configuration in AWS Elastic Beanstalke server?

I've tried to use manually

```php
php artisan queue:listen
php artisan queue:work
```

Both failed.

Comment: What do they fail with?

Comment: @mrhn when I use the command and just "freeze" my terminal and don't run the queues.

Comment: you can setup a systemd service to restart the queue on deployments. Instructions given in this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/987069/how-to-make-laravel-queue-work-in-aws-beanstalk/1011923#1011923)

Comment: @ThiagoValente: where you have run these command `php artisan queue:work`

Answer (score 5):

Things to check:

1. Try specifying the connection name: `php artisan queue:work database`
2. Else make sure your env file on EC2 refers to correct default QUEUE_DRIVER `QUEUE_DRIVER=database` in this case
3. Check config/queue.php for right default settings, if you don't specify queue driver in env file `default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database')`
4. Run `php artisan config:cache` on your EC2 instance for reload the env changes.

And you only need to use only one of the 2 commands, recommended is `php artisan queue:work` as its caches application state but run `php artisan queue:restart` every time you push code changes.

It is recommended to install and configure supervisor: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#supervisor-configuration

It will take care of restarting the queue worker on EC2 restart or queue failure

Comment: Your checklist worked for me. My queue was not working only because I did not use  php artisan config:cache. After giving this command my queue worked like a charm. thanks a lot

Comment: Did you rely on EB Worker or Supervisor in custom EC2?

Comment: I used Supervisor