# Laravel 5.4 Cron Job for Mail Queue not working on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: laravel-5, amazon-ec2, cron, queue

I have created a cron job on my EC2 instance for sending email from queue. It shows running the corn command every minute but I see tasks remain in my jobs table. I've already searched and tried existing solutions but failed to figure out the problem. Although queue working on my local server when I run 
`php artisan schedule:run`

My code in kernel:

```
$schedule->command('queue:work')
            ->everyMinute()
            ->withoutOverlapping();
```

Command I added in the file using crontab -e

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/prod_back/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

This is the output I see in terminal when I run `sudo service cron status`

```
May 07 13:50:01 ip-172-31-39-27 CRON[20260]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
May 07 13:50:01 ip-172-31-39-27 CRON[20261]: (ubuntu) CMD (/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/prod_back/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
May 07 13:50:01 ip-172-31-39-27 CRON[20260]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem. I got a community help that pointed out my cron command is wrong. I was running schedule command instead of queue command. So I changed it from

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/prod_back/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

to

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/prod_back/artisan queue:work >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

One more thing, I also had to run below command to reload my env changes from sync to database for queue driver.

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/prod_back/artisan config:cache
```

Please go to this link below and follow the checklist for diagnosing your specific problem in this regard.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738157/laravel-queue-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk
```

Comment: I would like to know how you run the corn command on the AWS server